# Google App Engine datastore remote integration

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence, google-cloud-datastore, integration

How would one go about using the Google App Engine datastore as a database for remote stand alone java programs?

Is anyone aware of a framework that could serialize the entities and make them available in other projects as java model classes?

Currently, I'm using a homebrewn servlet deployed on GAE which breaks it down to JSON (GSON) and then rebuild it at arrival, this is beginning to get messy now that the project has grown, and is not really flexible.

I do also need to persist some entities from javascript, alas the servlet/json/ajax mash. Someone pointed me towards the REST framework, would you agree?

Comment: This depends entirely on what you want to do with it. Simply exposing the datastore remotely is likely a very bad idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want their [ProtoRPC API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/).